# Summation of series reciprocal of quadratic

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been trying to find a formula for the series 
$$1\over x^2 + 3x + 2$$
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Changed. I meant x^2.

Comment: You don't specify the initial term !

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear, I wanted to know if there is a formula for the sum of the series.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}$$

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @JohnA.: you haven't understood my comment. If we don't know what the initial term is, we can't give a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you ask about a series with reciprocal quadratic terms, here is a summation formula:
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n {1\over k^2+3k+2} = {n\over2n+4}.
$$
This formula can be proved by induction. Taking the limit we have
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {1\over k^2+3k+2} = {1\over2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac1{x^2+3x+2}=\frac1{(x+1)(x+2)}=\frac1{x+1}-\frac1{x+2}$$ and the series telescopes.